# How to eval string in NSURL URLWithString

Tags: ios6

I'm trying to load an image - I get the URL from a JSON - dictionary

The dictionary:
api.amioamio.com/?v=1&id=2&pass=8d4a9a5648640eca8f8da4416d0f6999&cmd=getShop&p%5BshopId%5D=110

I works fine when I write it - but if I try to use a string-variable - it can't make the imageURL

Heres my code:

NSString *strURLTemp=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"[[[images objectForKey:@\"%@\"] objectForKey:@\"images\"] objectForKey:@\"small\"]",[keys objectAtIndex:0]];

```
NSLog(@"%@",strURLTemp);//[[[images objectForKey:@"78044"] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"small"]


//NSURL *imageURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[images objectForKey:@"100256"] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"small"]];

NSURL *imageURL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:strURLTemp];
NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL1];
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
```

How can I make this work ? Thanks !

Comment: what are you getting for strURLTemp?

Comment: Im getting the line after NSLOG in comment

Comment: What is the value for strURLTemp?

Comment: [[[images objectForKey:@"78044"] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"small"]

Comment: Okay, what is being printed by the NSLog statement?

Comment: Its the same:2012-12-06 16:54:30.494 AmioShopViewer[321:11303] 

[[[images objectForKey:@"78044"] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:@"small"]

Comment: So you're trying to get a URL that is based on a dictionary entry?

Comment: yes this is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Could you put up the contents of the JSON dictionary in the question?

Comment: the URL is now in top of the question - I have chosen a id of 110 - it varies

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have a run-time compiler/interpreter.  You need to write what you want to do as source to compile rather than trying to generate lines of code as strings inside the running program.

Comment: Thanks
I'll have to find out how to do this so.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: I found out - I used the URL from the database and added the productId